# No-chatting VoIP smartphone application

Tags: windows, android, privacy, voip

I am looking for a no-chatting VoIP smartphone application which can run at least on *Android* and has the following features:

### Necessary features

- Isn't owned by *Facebook, inc.*
- Is gratis to use
- Gives the option to allow or disallow video calling (as to have voice-only or voice-video calls per preference)
- If voice messages are even possible, the application includes an option to block getting and/or sending voice messages (henceforth, the application is voice-call only oriented)

### Non necessary features

- [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software)
- Has the option to print a warning each time before a video button was mistakenly clicked to turn on video in a voice call (if video is allowed for a given end-user)
- Allows usage without a phone number (based on email and/or account → if someone wants that)
- Isn't necessarily aimed only for smartphones and could also work on a PC

### My question

What would be an example of such no-chatting VoIP smartphone application?

Comment: May I point you to [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_cheapcall#group_858) again? Linphone might fit that (available for Android from F-Droid and thus FOSS; they also have clients for Linux, Mac and Windows; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linphone) for details. Not sure if it fits the other terms, e.g. warning on video – it's quite a while ago I last used it). Jami wouldn't fit the "no-chatting" requirement.

Comment: Hello dear @Izzy thank you for pointing me that again because I recall that I didn't notice the list - a random cognitive bias I guess ; I am sorry for this.

Comment: No prob. If you find something that fits, be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) :)

Comment: Hello @Izzy I just checked Limphone website --- they do seem to have to chatting in the application... Regarding the list, it is headed `Open SIP clients`. What is the meaning of this please? Thanks,

Comment: "Open SIP clients" means simply that they are not bound to a specific service – i.e. you can configure servers and all. As opposed to a preconfigured app using the SIP protocol but only letting you use ACME Inc (or whatever), as the server URL is fixed and cannot be changed by the user.